# Upgrade from Tex Live 2022 to 2023, but the Tex Live version is still 2022 in Linux (Debian)

Tags: texlive, update

I have upgraded from Tex Live 2022 to 2023 by [the link](https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html). After having done those, the `which tlmgr` outputs `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr`, but `tex --version`  outputs:

```
TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2022)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

Have I successfully upgraded from Tex Live 2022 to 2023? Thanks.

Comment: Adjust your PATH in your startup files to point to .../2023/bin/platform instead of .../2022/....

Comment: @hair-splitter `vim ~/.bashrc` gets `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:${PATH}`. Is it right?

Comment: I can enter into the directory of `/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux# `, but when enter the `$PATH`, it display an error: `/usr/games:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux: No such file or directory`. Weird. @hair-splitter

Comment: You need `tlmgr update --self --all`.

Comment: @Clara Yes, it is all right now.